# I'm trying to use monogame on my home computer for a school project (my school makes us use visual studio 2019) but it won't work

Tags: visual-studio-2019, monogame

I added the monogame files into the project templates folder in vs 2019, but it just gives me this error and I have no idea how to fix it:

Error I get

[image: 1]

I've tried deleting and redownloading the monogame files multiple times and it works on the computers at school by doing the same thing that I did, but won't work on my home computer. When I tried to open a project on my home computer that I created on a school computer it corrupted it and I had to redo the project.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. Attempting to close it because of the mention of school and homework, is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install [Monogame 3.7](https://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-3-7-1/11173).

There was no "corruption"  of the source files, only the project and .sln files.

Everything you wrote still exists in the source .cs files, simply copy the .cs files from your old project to the new one.